# Console Output to a File not using SetOut

Tags: c#, dll, console

I am calling Gurobi (several times) from C#. The Console output is, therefore, a mixture of mine and the Gurobi logging. If I overwrite Console.Out, only my output is redirected, but Gurobi (apparently wrapping an unmanaged dll) still writes to the screen.

Is there any way to get every line from the Console (as string or file)?

Comment: Nothing you can do about that from a C# program, use the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gurobi/console) to find other programmers with the same problem.  Plenty of hits, the LogToConsole configuration variable looks attractive, contact the vendor if you need more support.

Comment: Ok, then I guess I have to let Gurobi write its output to files, read them back and combine them to built a log file ... I hoped there would be any way to "listen" to the Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture Gurobi's console output using a callback object.  The callback object has a `Callback()` method which is called for many reasons, one of which is to tell you about text it is about to write to the Console.  You can do whatever you want with this text.  In the example below I write the text as debug output:

```
class MyGRBCallback : GRBCallback
{
    protected override void Callback()
    {
        if (this.where == GRB.Callback.MESSAGE)
        {
            String text = this.GetStringInfo(GRB.Callback.MSG_STRING);
            Debug.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

You tell Gurobi about your callback object using the GRBModel's `SetCallback` method.

```
var env = new GRBEnv();
var m = new GRBModel(env);
var callback = new MyGRBCallback();
m.SetCallback(callback);
```

Gurobi will call your callback AND write to the console at this point.  You can tell Gurobi not to write to the console:

```
env.Set(GRB.IntParam.LogToConsole, 0);
```